# AMD APU-A4-5000 processor issue

Tags: cpu, cpuinfo

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Toshiba Satellite C50D-A 40010 Laptop (PSCGYG-00J00J). My AMD A4 processor's speed is 1.5GHz but Ubuntu shows it as 800MHz.

```
dharmesh@home:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 22
model       : 0
model name  : AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x700010b
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb perfctr_l2 arat xsaveopt hw_pstate proc_feedback npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 2994.37
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate [11]

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 22
model       : 0
model name  : AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics    
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x700010b
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb perfctr_l2 arat xsaveopt hw_pstate proc_feedback npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 2994.37
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate [11]

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 22
model       : 0
model name  : AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics    
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x700010b
cpu MHz     : 1300.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb perfctr_l2 arat xsaveopt hw_pstate proc_feedback npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 2994.37
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate [11]

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 22
model       : 0
model name  : AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics    
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x700010b
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb perfctr_l2 arat xsaveopt hw_pstate proc_feedback npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 2994.37
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate [11]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/proc/cpuinfo` shows the *current* frequency for each core.

Your processor is an APU (Accelerated Processing Unit). This is something like a CPU with automatic frequency regulation. However, if the driver is missing, the APU can't know how much is needed of it and will therefore stay at its minimum ever.

You can solve this by installing the proprietary AMD Graphics driver `fglrx`.
Open *Software & Updates* (via Dash or System Settings), go to *Additional Drivers*, and choose the option saying *fglrx* for your Graphics card. It may take some time to install. After a reboot, the APU should adapt its frequency as needed, and you have better options for your Graphics via the newly installed *AMD Catalyst Control Center*.

Comment: @the-seppi.....thanks for the help. after installing proprietary AMD drivers now its showing 1500MHz as desired. Thanks once again